# lubuntu power manager closed after every boot

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, xfce4-power-manager

The power manager on lubuntu 13.10 does not run automatically. After every time I boot my lubuntu, I have to manually open the power manager. How to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a bug in lubuntu 13.10,

upgrading to 14.04 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I could not figure it out how to run it automatically; so I added a alias on the desktop. I know, I know, that's probably the wrong way, but that's how I managed.

Comment: that is same as running it mannually every single time you boot your system. this makes no sense.